# Angularjs form validation in MVC view not showing error message

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

here is a simple MVC view, in here i am trying to work out form validation using angularJS. For example, you can see that if username is more than 16 characters long it should push the message to screen saying "Username cannot be longer than 16 characters".

Am i missing anything? as this is not working. I have a link to AngularJS file in _layout.cshtml.

Here is the Razor View:

```
<style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "myForm" }))
{        

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl">

        <div class="login-wrapper">

            <div class="panel panel-default" style="width: 500px;">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Log in to Birch Intranet</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtUsername">Username:</label>
                        <input type="text"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="txtUsername"
                            name="Username"
                            ng-model="Username"
                            placeholder="Username"
                            ng-maxlength="16" required />

                        <div class="error"
                            ng-show="myForm.Username.$dirty && myForm.Username.$invalid">
                            <small class="error"
                                ng-show="myForm.Username.$error.required">Username is required.
                            </small>
                            <small class="error"
                                ng-show="myForm.Username.$error.minlength">Username is required to be at least 3 characters
                            </small>
                            <small class="error"
                                ng-show="myForm.Username.$error.maxlength">Username cannot be longer than 16 characters
                            </small>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="txtPassword">Password:</label>
                        <input type="password"
                            class="form-control"
                            id="txtPassword"
                            name="Password"
                            ng-model="Password"
                            placeholder="Password"
                            ng-maxlength="2" required />
                        <div class="error"
                            ng-show="myForm.Password.$dirty && Password.$invalid">
                            <small class="error"
                                ng-show="myForm.Password.$error.required">Password is required.
                            </small>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="remember" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <input id="remember-me" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
}

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('validateCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.Username = 'Username';
        $scope.Password = 'Password';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do the other validation messages (required and minlength) show? Inspect the element and see if it has the class ng-invalid-maxlength. Also, look into ng-messages.

Comment: none of the error messages show. I will inspect in chrome, thanks.

Comment: Are you using creating more than one module ("myApp") in your Angular code? If not, move the ng-app="myApp" to the html tag in your layout file. In Chrome, check your sources tab to see if all the required JavaScript files are there.

Comment: Yes, there will be more modules to come in angular, so we can't move it to layout. checking under source tab its got angular.min.js + bootstrap etc at the top in head section.

Comment: What about your app.js, controllers.js, etc? Basically, is anything working with your angular code?

Comment: I am just starting with Angular, I have not yet created/separated app.js or controller.js. My controller is defined in the script tag within the view. I am just taking baby steps, before I can separate these js modules into their own files. Nothing is currently working with angular code. I had it all working with form tag before, but now that i have replaced form tag with Html.BeginForm its not working anymore.